# Trying to insert column data into mysql from json array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert a JSON Array (objects?!)  into mysql with php.  When the data comes through as Rows, I can handle that!  However, I had to export the array in a different manner, and now I'm not able to figure it out.  After `$array=json_decode($posted,true);`, my array looks like:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Allen, test
            [1] => Anderson, Jayson
            [2] => Barrett, Kayla
            [3] => Bennett, Amira
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => testallen@gmail.com
            [1] => testjayson@yahoo.com
            [2] => testkayla@gmail.com
            [3] => testamira@hotmail.com
        )
)
```

How can I get this into a foreach loop that outputs:

```
insert into table (name, email) values("Allen, test","testallen@gmail.com")
insert into table (name, email) values("Anderson, Jayson","testjayson@yahoo.com")
... etc?
```

When the data was in a 'row' format, it was easy for me ..

```
          foreach($array as $row)
          {   
$query="insert into table (name, email) values(\"$row[0]\",\"$row[1]\")";
$doit = mysqli_query($con,$query);
          }
```

But now that the array is not coming through in rows, I cant quite figure it out.

Comment: You will need to use the index here to access the corresponding data in the other array (or both, of you switch out the `foreach` for a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to loop the $row[0] and use the key to get both values:

```
foreach($row[0] as $key => $value) {
    $name = $row[0][$key];
    $email = $row[1][$key];
    $query = "insert into table (name, email) values('$name', '$email')";
    $doit = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
```

[Working sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3867e94c845b35d10ebb274ef4f34726deccfb47)

However, I strongly encourage you using [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead of string variables in your queries to prevent from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is this better:`$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO TemporaryUserEmail (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);

foreach($row[0] as $key => $value) {
    $name = $row[0][$key];
    $email = $row[1][$key];
    $stmt->execute();
    }

$stmt->close();
$con->close();`

Comment: Yes, I thought the bind_param() should be in the loop but I've just checked and it seems correct this way. Much better with prepared statements

Comment: It works both inside and outside the loop.  Does it matter where I put the bind_param ? Is it more efficient one way or the other?

Comment: It seems actually better outside, what you can do it once is always better. Thanks for listening to me and use prepared statements. I'm glad I could help.